# Gradle - creating multiple jars within project

Tags: java, spring, gradle, jar

Recently I got a requirement to separete a very small portion of the logic from a single-module gradle project into shared library, and upload it into private nexus. The logic behind it is that I want to create new micro service that will execute scheduled jobs (until now it was the responsibility of this single-module service), but we want to use the same repository classes that we already have in current project. I was wondering what is the best practice in this situation.

At first I didn't want to refactor the project into multi-module, because I would need to create two modules, move over 200 classes to the "main" module, and only few to "shared" module, so I just created a simple gradle task that will create a jar from files in one source set, and push it to maven, but i started to wondering if it is a anti-pattern this approach could be problematic in the future. Should I instead refactor the project into multiple modules and introduce more complexity but avoid custom gradle task?

code sample:

```
sourceSets {
    create("shared") {
        java.srcDirs("src/shared/java")
        resources.srcDir("src/shared/resources")
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output + sourceSets.test.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output + sourceSets.test.get().output
        addExtendsFromRelation("sharedImplementation", "implementation", true)
        addExtendsFromRelation("sharedRuntimeOnly", "runtimeOnly", true)
    }

val sharedLibJar = tasks.register("sharedLibJar", Jar::class){
    from(sourceSets["shared"].output)
    archiveFileName.set("foo.jar")
}
publishing{
    publications{
        create<MavenPublication>("fooLibrary") {
            artifact(sharedLibJar)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you would end up with more complexity keeping them together in the end.  You would have to manage dependencies, paths, artifacts, and everything else otherwise, all with custom tasks and lots of other work.  Multi-module builds are pretty common, and the support is directly in gradle/directory structure.  As long as you recognize the pattern, there isn't a whole lot of complexity introduced doing it that way.